# Express Mongoose automated caching?

Tags: node.js, express, caching, mongoose

One weird observation that I got today was like this:

We have a REST API made with **NodeJS**, **express** and **mongoose**.
There is a `GET` endpoint `/api/cars` that returns a list of cars from the Car model fairly simply:

```
app.get('/cars', (req, res, next) => {
    Car.find()
        .exec()
        .then(cars => {
            res.status(200).send(cars);
        }, error => {
            next(error);
        });
});
```

What was interesting is that accessing the endpoint through the browser a second time returned with a status code `304`, which means it did cache it (modifying the list in the database changes the status back to `200`). However, I don't quite understand where it happened and who did it.
Interstingly, if I manually cache the list in the **Redis** database and retrieve it from there, the response is always `200` even though the data did not modify at all. So is it a part of **mongoose** then?

I mean I appreciate the automatic caching, but I want to know how it happens.
We aren't using a specific caching module for express.

Answer (score 0):

304 means the Resource hasnt been modified

> Indicates that the resource has not been modified since the version specified by the request headers If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match. In such case, there is no need to retransmit the resource since the client still has a previously-downloaded copy

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304)

Also see RFC7232 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232

This is browser caching, the headers that were sent before weren't modified. When you manually edit the DB they will be edited... Hence you dont get a browser cache copy, but you download a new copy.

Comment: So why I'm not getting the same result if I retrieve the unmodified data from Redis instead of mongoDB?

Comment: This also depends on the headers / the configuration. I can guess: Does Redis send a "Last-Modified" header? Is the other configuration sending it? Edit: And if so, whats the content?